# Associative Array display not working

Tags: php

I am trying to call an associative array and I am confused why this would not work.

if I `print_r($test);` it shows the following:

```
Array(
[e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9] => Array(
        [rowid] => e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9
        [id] => 3
        [qty] => 1
        [price] => 20
        [name] => test
        [options] => Array(
                [permName] => large
            )
        [subtotal] => 20
    )
)
```

but if I do `$test[0]["rowid"];` it gives the following error Message: Undefined offset: 0

I am still a php newbie but from what I have learned about arrays so far this should work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is associative so `$test[0]` doesn't exist.

```
$test['e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9']['rowid']
```

If you want to get the first element without referencing the key you can use `reset($test)`

```
$first_element = reset($test);
$first_element['row_id'];
```

The two examples are functionality identical.

Comment: Haha, haven't that in your original answer, you could safe me few strikes on keyboard. He always can get referencing key by `key()`, I think it's worth mentioning. Anyway +1.

Comment: I am sorry if this is a stupid question but I was under the impression that you can use 0,1,2 even in associative arrays. Is it safe to say I was wrong?

Comment: @Claremont Correct, you can't use integer values to access the Nth value of an associative array. The exception to that is if you set it yourself (i.e. `array('foo' => 'bar', 0 => 'myVar')`). If you really wanted to you can dump the keys and force a re-number by using `$test = array_values($test);`. Then you can access `$test[0]`, `$test[1]` and so on

Answer (score 1):

Your outter array seems to have the key "e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9" - its not indexed numerically.

So you should use

```
 $test["e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9"]["rowid"]
```

You can also use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) if you want to find out what the first non-numerical key is

Answer (score 0):

You either can use key `$test['e7a36fadf2410205f0768da1b61156d9']['rowid'] as [Mike B suggested][1]. Or get first element of array with [`reset()`][2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php):

```
$element = reset( $test);
$element['rowid'];
```

Or use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) if you will need to work with those keys later (you can always get current key with [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)):

```
$keys = array_keys( $test);
$test[ $keys[0]]['rowid'];
```

And if you need to browse all records in test just use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach( $test as $key => $item){
    $item['rowid'];
}
```